# Quelle serait une meilleure façon de dire « Il est constamment sur son téléphone »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

J’ai l’impression que « être sur téléphone » n’est pas une tournure idiomatique. Devrais-je plutôt dire « Il passe son temps sur/à consulter son téléphone? D’autres propositions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il existe toutes sortes de possibilités de registre plutôt courant.

- Il est **collé** à son téléphone. (*registre très familier**)

([réf.](https://www.mamanvogue.fr/mon-conjoint-est-colle-a-son-smartphone-a-laide/)) Mon conjoint est collé à son smartphone, à l’aide !

- Il est **soudé** à son téléphone en permanence (*registre de familier à courant*)

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Baisse_la_t%C3%AAte_t_auras_l_air_d_un_coure/JzQgHAAACAAJ?hl=en)) Tout le monde au village connaît Nono, onze ans, l'enfant éternellement soudé à son vélo.

- Il n'**a de temps que pour** son téléphone (*registre courant*)

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dis_Papa_C_est_Quoi_le_12e_Secret_du_Bon/OqiyxgEACAAJ?hl=en)) Marc, directeur de recherche d'un laboratoire d'astrophysique n'a de temps que pour ses travaux et ses étudiants.

- Il est **absorbé/accaparé** en permanence par son téléphone (*registre courant à littéraire*)

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_%C3%89v%C3%A9nement_du_jeudi/yRYyAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+absorb%C3%A9+par+sa%22&dq=%22est+absorb%C3%A9+par+sa%22&printsec=frontcover)) On traverse le continent sans pour autant le voir vraiment, comme avec l'œil de Le Lann qui, entre l'ennui, sa chambre d'hôtel, ses cuites et l'attente de la nuit, est absorbé par sa musique et se fiche du reste. (*Le temps qui reste est investi dans la musique.*)

- **Il ne se passe pas une minute sans** qu'il soit en train de se servir de son téléphone. (*registre courant à littéraire*)

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22se%20passe%20pas%20une%20minute%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+se+passe+pas+une+minute+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cse%20passe%20pas%20une%20minute%3B%2Cc0)) Il ne se passe pas une minute pour ainsi dire sans qu'on ne téléphone pour demander des renseignements ou pour en donner.

Comment: Je te remercie pour ta réponse LPH, c’est très aimable de ta part!

Comment: *Il n'a de temps que pour son téléphone* n'est pas très courant. Je n'avais en fait jamais entendu ou lu cette tournure.

Comment: Pourquoi fais-tu une différence de registre entre "collé à son téléphone" et "soudé à son téléphone", et spécialement dans ce sens ?

Comment: @jlliagre Selon l'idée que je me fais de ces termes, dans ce contexte particulier "coller" a un sens plutôt donné par définition, alors que "souder" prendrait  plutôt son sens dans la métaphore, serait plus littéraire, mais je n'ai peut-être pas  trop bien exprimé la différence qu'il semble y avoir ; par exemple "coller" dans ce sens est certainement plus ou moins péjoratif, alors que "souder" ne le serait peut-être pas du tout.

Comment: Les deux sont nécessairement des métaphores mais soudé (au sens propre) est plus "irréversible" et beaucoup plus rare dans ce contexte.

Comment: @jlliagre Je pensais à ça : Une métaphore morte se définit comme une « métaphore lexicalisée, dont la qualité figurative et poétique n'est plus ressentie ».

Answer (score 4):

En France :

> Il est (constamment/toujours) **scotché** à son portable/téléphone.

Ailleurs, remplacer *portable* par *GSM*, *cellulaire*, *Natel*, etc. en fonction de la dénomination locale de l'objet en question...

[image]

On trouve aussi le très courant ***pendu** à son [...]* mais l'image me semble moins pertinente depuis que les téléphones n'ont plus de fil...

Comment: Encore merci jilliagre, tes réponses sont toujours les bienvenues   .

Answer (score 3):

À l'oral je dis spontanément :

> Il est toujours/tout le temps sur son [cell(ulaire](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8393991)).

À l'écrit je choisirais *toujours* et j'écrirais *cellulaire* au complet. Il y a un certain nombre d'expressions figées et de locutions verbales avec *être* et la préposition [*sur*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur/0) et pour moi (locuteur du Québec) l'exemple que j'ai donné est bien naturel (et je suis curieux de savoir s'il l'est en France ou ailleurs).

La question de l'emploi de la préposition dans [*sur le cellulaire*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4583) est particulièrement stimulante. Cet emploi de la préposition depuis quelques décennies serait conforme à la représentation du moyen de communication comme support de transmission et aussi justifiable par la perception d'un réseau comme une superficie ou une aire ; dans un style plus soigné ou quand la métaphore trouve moins d'écho, comme avec le téléphone classique, on pourrait préférer les prépositions *à, dans* ou *par* selon le cas. (BDL). *...au cellulaire*.

Comment: Oui, en France aussi, *il est tout le temps **sur** son portable* va très bien.

Comment: Intéressant! Merci pour ta réponse némésie-t-île.

Answer (score 0):

En lisant la question, j'ai pensé spontanément à :

> - Il a constamment les yeux rivés sur son téléphone.
> - Il ne décolle pas (les yeux) de son téléphone.

Où téléphone peut être remplacé par : portable, mobile, smartphone etc.